# Querying a json type string Postgres

Tags: arrays, json, string, postgresql

I have a text column in my db with a json structure.   Postgres v.10

It could look like this:

```
{"pe_cd":"07","me_cd":"006","mf":"4.0","mfm":"4.0","pot":null,"earliestDate":[{"date":"2019-07-01","_destroy":false},{"date":"2020-01-01","_destroy":""}],"earliestDate2":null,"leavingDate":null}
```

If earliestDate2 = null then i need to make a update query and fill this with the first date from the earliestDate[]. In this case 2019-07-01

Goal in this case should be:

```
{"pe_cd":"07","me_cd":"006","mf":"4.0","mfm":"4.0","pot":null,"earliestDate":[{"date":"2019-07-01","_destroy":false},{"date":"2020-01-01","_destroy":""}],"earliestDate2":"2019-07-01","leavingDate":null}
```

How can i write this update query?

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3c393/1)

Answer (score 0):

to query your json type string, you can do this:

`SELECT * FROM yourtable
WHERE json_like_column::JSON->'earliestDate' IS NULL

`

:: will cast your string into JSON
and -> will get 'eraliestDate' field from your json. you can also use ->> to convert the value of that field to string.

Comment: You should replace `WHERE json_like_column::JSON->'earliestDate' IS NULL` by `WHERE json_like_column::JSON->'earliestDate' = 'null' :: json`, because the json 'null' value is different from the postgres `NULL` value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with for you:

```
WITH null_dates AS
( -- Find the records with a NULL earliestDate2 and expand the dates stored
    SELECT id, (jsonb_array_elements((attr::JSONB)->'earliestDate')->>'date')::DATE as d
      FROM test
     WHERE (attr::JSONB)->>'earliestDate2' IS NULL
)
UPDATE test t
   SET attr = ((attr::JSONB)||jsonb_build_object('earliestDate2', sub.edate))::TEXT
  FROM
     ( -- Get the min date per ID from CTE (null_dates)
         SELECT id
              , MIN(d) AS edate
           FROM null_dates
          GROUP BY id
     ) sub
 WHERE t.id = sub.id
;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=53058ff2bacbe2e1e8c84022f3f0e731) is a fiddle to show it in action.

Comment: jsonb_array_elements doesnt exist in v.10 :(

Comment: It's listed in the documentation for Postgres 10 and when I run that fiddle in Postgres 10 it completes. Pretty sure I've used it in practice with v10 also. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Your fiddle is using v9.3

Comment: I must have made some mistake it seems to work but i still can't make the update. I think the problem is that this column attr is a text field in my db. Do i need to cast everything back to text? ERROR: syntax error at or near "::" .

Comment: I'll update the example here to work with `TEXT` but it would be a better solution to store it as `JSON` or `JSONB`. Pretty sure you can pass `TEXT` in an `INSERT` statement and Postgres will implicitly convert it.

Comment: Perfect it works! Thanks a lot, what i noticed is that the updated object in my json now comes at the end of the json(text). Is there some way to say  put that value for example in another position? Or doesn't it make any difference when reading the data?

Comment: Probably doesn't make a difference when reading the JSON's top level data. Depends on the client I suppose but typically you're accessing the data by key and not in order. You can use `jsonb_set()` or `jsonb_insert()` if you want to specify a path but in my experience that's where things start to get messy and more of a pain to deal with.